# Force Maven to fail the build if locally cached snapshot is purged from Nexus

Tags: maven, build

1. Let there be a project referencing a library snapshot version, say `library:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`.
2. Build the project locally, causing Maven to pull `library:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` into its local cache.
3. Purge `library:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` from Nexus (or your artifact storage of choice), perhaps by `mvn release`ing the library.
4. Build the project locally again, perhaps with `--update-snapshots` - *it succeeds*!

The question here is:
How can I make it so that Maven **fails** the build locally when a remote snapshot is purged?

I would like to achieve this feat in a Continuous Integration system, which means that the solution requiring me to obliterate the entire local cache prior to building is not possible. Also not possible will be to introspect the POM of the project and surgically delete artifacts from the local cache prior to building.

Note: I have filed [#MNG-5245](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5425) with Maven, hoping to expedite the creation of this feature if missing. So if you find this bug report, please resist the temptation of using it as an answer.

Comment: I am using Maven 2, in case it matters.

Comment: Don't understand the problem with periodically purging the local repository. All caches get dirty over time. I personally like simple cache refresh logic :-)

Comment: *Periodic* purges may still get you wrong build results. I would like to have Maven check the status of the dependencies in Nexus before each build, preferably in a less costly manner than a purge. A purge will pay the high price of downloading the same artifact that was deleted most of the time for most of my dependencies, since dependencies in my case change at a slow page.

Comment: High cost? How slow is your network? Never mind not important.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that while periodic purges are not necessarily high cost, they do not give me the guarantee that I'm building with existing snapshots. Conversely, pre-build purges give me that guarantee, but they become high cost by repeatedly downloading the same artifacts before each build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I can think of is, before you build locally, first do a local repository purge for the snapshots in your local repository.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/purge-local-repository-mojo.html

The reason for your "success" build is because Maven actually can find corresponding snapshot artifacts in your local repo.  As Maven don't have "stale" artifact concept, all locally stored artifacts are actually valid ones (including snapshots).  The best you can do is to make sure there is no snapshots artifacts in your local repository and force Maven to download from your remote repo.  However it only works if all your dependencies are downloaded from remote repo.

Comment: Nice, so there is a way to purge selectively, acting only on the dependencies of the project to be built, which will be much faster than a directory delete.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will still be more costly than it needs to be, since most of the time we will be deleting and then downloading the same artifacts over and over again.

Comment: The option to purge *only* snapshot dependencies is probably the best we can get, and likely a fair price to pay at this stage for guaranteeing a correct build. Since this was the first answer to mention this plugin, I have accepted it.

Answer (score 1):

No, Maven doesn't support this. I can't imagine a problem to which it would be the right solution, either. I suggest you ask another question and explain what you're trying to accomplish. You may find there's a better way to get there.

Comment: The problem I'm trying to resolve here is simple. If some project forgets to update a dependency from a snapshot version to a release version, and that snapshot version disappears from Nexus, I want that project to fail to build, and I want it to do so without paying the high price of purging the local cache. It is a simple generalization of a case that Maven already handles: if a snapshot is *updated* in Nexus, Maven can be made to reflect the change in its local cache. Why should it not be the same for *deletions*?

Answer (score 1):

The Maven dependency plugin has a [purge local repository](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/purge-local-repository-mojo.html) goal that may be configured to remove specific artifacts from the local repo.  If you make release builds on the same server hosting your CI service (and thus the local repo that needs to be purged) you might be able to add an execution of `dependency:purge-local-repository` to a profile that gets activated by the Maven release plugin during `release:perform`.

Note, this does nothing to clear local repos on individual development machines.

Comment: I guess I see your idea. Purge the local copy from my build agent upon release. That won't work well, because there is more than one agent. But I can still use that goal before each build, unless it's going to get really slow...

Comment: I accepted Ardian's answer, since it came first. +1 for your answer.